# Web deploy failure after IIS recycle

Tags: iis-7, webdeploy, recycle

I locked up my database (during SQL dev) which supports my Web app, so I recycled the application pool to kill the session. Then corrected the db code. Now when I go to try and deploy via webdeploy I get a 'not all data is available' error. My IIS administrator restarted webdeploy but I still get the error as it seems it can't publish to the web deploy package directory. Any thoughts on why this may happen? Tried many things, restart all pools, confirmed deployment works on two other sites. So it's definitely on the IIS side. thanks

Comment: Can you include the exact error information? Also, try running `msdeploy.exe` with `-verbose` (or possibly `-debug`) to get more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, I thought I replied earlier, but my IIS administrator said it was a false correlation (the recycle stopping the service). He restarted the MVC service and all went well. Thanks